# Ionic how to show card in col and row

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am tring to build a simple grid in which there is a card i need to show cards by 2x2 format.

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let data of dataa" > let assume it will be 10
        <ion-card style="width: 200px;">

          <img src="assets/imgs/shoe-air.jpg">

          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-badge>Available</ion-badge>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col style="text-align: right; font-size: 20px;">
                <ion-icon name="heart" color="secondary" ></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>

           <ion-button class="offer">{{(2500 - 2000) /2500*100}}%</ion-button>
           <p><span class="regular-price" >RS. 2000<span class="special-price"><del>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RS. 2500</del></span></span></p>

        </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Its just a template so there is only one card. but when ill fetch data it will be 9 or 8.
I need to show like this

```
2x2
2x2
2x2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[The responsive grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/grid) in Ionic is based on a 12 column layout.

If you want to have a 2-column wide (each column takes up 50%) grid, set `size=6` on your columns like so:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let data of dataa">
      <ion-card>
          ....
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```